# How to find the value from Array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array, I want the result to be like this: type id, name. username, password, email.

```
        Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [id] => 1
    [1] => xyz
    [name] => xyz
    [2] => admin
    [username] => admin
    [3] => 200820e3227815ed1756a6b531e7e0d2
    [password] => 200820e3227815ed1756a6b531e7e0d2
    [4] => xyz@gmail.com
    [email] => xyz@gmail.com
)
```

Comment: I think you're trying to solve the wrong problem. You should focus on fixing whatever is giving you such a badly structured array.

Comment: Arrays usually work best when every element stored in the array is an object of the same type: numbers, strings, regular expression, objects of a specific class... a giant mixture of elements of different types is rarely a good idea with arrays.

Comment: @bradley.ayers: This "badly structured array" was obtained through a FETCH_ASSOC (PDO), fetch_array (mysql) or similar (instead of fetch_assoc). What OP needs to focus on right now is actually writing an actual question. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here this array key [0] and [id] is same, because these are the same as in a table, so you can fetch the value form database like this

```
$query = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM yourtablename');
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
   echo $row['name'];
   echo $row['username'];
   echo $row['password'];
   echo $row['email'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`myArray['name']` would return xyz.  Where myArray is the name of your array.